# bootstrap: как "эмулировать" нажатие на bootstrap - кнопку из javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Господа,

я в очередной раз задаю не очень умный вопрос. Но я поискал, и не нашел какого то понятного решения.

У меня есть пример создания модального окна. Это не первый пример, который я нашел, но первый, который работает так, как мне и надо: 1) окно располагаются поверх всего документа 2) Клик вне модального элемента автоматически закрывает его

Ниже - сам пример: (полный код html - старницы, со всеми подключенными библиотеками)

А вот что мне нужно: пример работает при нажатии на bootstrap - овскую кнопку. А я хочу кнопку убрать, а окно показывать из javascript.

У bootstrap - кнопки я вижу два свойства - `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"`, которые, видимо, и влияют на показ этой кнопки. Но как их активировать из js?

Спасибо большое за подсказки

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>modal dialog example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
            Запустить модальное окно
        </button>

  <a href="#" onclick="show_modal();">Открыть модальное окно средствами js</a>


  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>





  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    function show_modal() {
      // вот здесь я хотел бы показать модальный диалог программно
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё таки, несмотря на советы, мне не удалось заставить работать показ модального окна из JS.

После некотрых поисков я нашел вот такое решение. Его единственный недостаток - клик вне модального окна его не закрывает.

Я прошу прощения, но мне понравился подход, который используется в этой библиотеке: вместо возни с разными CSS свойствами я могу работать с объектами типа "окно" или "кнопка" почти так же легко, как в windows.

Код получается крайне простой и императивный.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsframe.js/lib/jsframe.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="show_modal();">Показть модальное окно</a>

    <script>

    
    //Show as a modal window
    function show_modal(){
        const jsFrame = new JSFrame();

        const innerHTML = '<div>' +
        '<h4>Content of modal window. For example, a message</h4>' +
        '</div>'

        const modalFrame = jsFrame.create({
            title: 'modal window',
            left: 100, top: 100, width: 320, height: 220,
            html: innerHTML
        });

        modalFrame.showModal(_frame => {
            _frame.closeFrame();
        });
    }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>modal dialog example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
            Запустить модальное окно
        </button>

  <a href="#" onclick="show_modal();">Открыть модальное окно средствами js</a>


  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>





  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    function show_modal() {
      // вот здесь я хотел бы показать модальный диалог программно
      document.querySelector('[data-target="#exampleModal"]').click();
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! А можно попросить одно небольшое уточнение: Ваш код document.querySelector('[data-target="#exampleModal"]').click(); прекрансо работает, когда у меня ЕСТЬ на странице bootstrap - кнопка. Но на том сайте, на котором я хочу использовать этот пример, этой кнопки нет - окно должно показываться только из JS. Нельзя ли то же самое сделать без bootstrap - кнопки?